# Azure Cognitive Search: How to get collection of strings from a view

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index definition on the Azure Cognitive Search and inside this index definition, there is a field called `CustomerNames` which of type collection `(Collection(Edm.String))`. Basically, this means my collection result will look like this: `CustomerNames: ["Homer Simpson", "Henry Griffin", "Jane Doe"]`

Here is the snapshot of the index definition:
[image]

Now I have a view that will act as a data source in this cognitive search and this view is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vCog_CustomerActivityAttachmentSearchDocuments]
AS
SELECT
    caa.Id,
    caa.CustomerActivityId,
    caa.AmsAttachmentId,
    caa.OriginalFileName,
    caa.[FileName],
    caa.FileExtension,
    caa.ContentType,
    caa.[Description],
    caa.DocumentTypeId,
    caa.AdditionalInfo,
    caa.Comments,
    ca.CustomerId,
    GuidCustomerId = ca.CustomerId,
    CustomerNames = 
    (    
    SELECT
    STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),cp.FirstName + ' ' + cp.LastName), ', ')
    FROM dbo.CustomerPersons AS cp with (nolock)
    WHERE cp.CustomerId = c.Id AND cp.LegalEntityName IS NULL
    ),
    CustomerPersons = 
    (
        Select
            cp.Id
            , cp.CustomerId
            , cp.NamePrefix
            , cp.FirstName
            , cp.MiddleName
            , cp.LastName
            , cp.DateOfBirth
            , cp.HomePhone
            , cp.WorkPhone
            , cp.CellPhone
            , cp.FaxPhone
            , cp.Email
            , cp.Email2
            , cp.LegalEntityName
        from
            CustomerPersons cp with (nolock)
        where
             cp.CustomerId = c.Id FOR JSON AUTO
    ),
    c.FirmName,
    ca.PolicyId,
    PolicyNumber = p.TrimmedPolicyNumber,
    caa.CreatedAtUtc,
    caa.[RowVersion]
FROM dbo.CustomerActivityAttachments caa with (nolock)
JOIN dbo.CustomerActivities ca with (nolock) on ca.Id = caa.CustomerActivityId
JOIN dbo.Customers c with (nolock) on c.Id = ca.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Policies p with (nolock) on p.Id = ca.PolicyId
where IsNull(caa.UpdatedAtUtc, caa.CreatedAtUtc) > GetDate() - 1200
GO
```

So when I run the indexer on the cognitive search, it is unable to recognize the CustomerNames and throwing the following error:

```
The data field 'CustomerNames' in the document with key 'XXXXXXXX' has an invalid value of type 'Edm.String' (String maps to Edm.String). The expected type was 'Collection(Edm.String)'.
```

So my question is how do I change my query in a way that I am getting a JSON array of strings and making it recognizable by the search function?

What I have tried so far: I have tried using this query inside the customerNames:

```
SELECT  
        JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),cp.FirstName + ' ' + cp.LastName), ', ') + '"' 
        FROM dbo.CustomerPersons AS cp with (nolock) 
        WHERE cp.CustomerId = c.Id AND cp.LegalEntityName IS NULL 
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']')  as [CustomerNames]
        FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

But this is not solving the problem. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Field mapping function - jsonArrayToStringCollection to convert the json array to Index collection

So let your query generate a column with name CustomerNamesJArray and map it to CustomerNames and have a jsonArrayToStringCollection mapping function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#field-mapping-functions